# How to import a microsoft access query with input parameters into excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have to import a microsoft access query into Excel.

The issue that I have with the import is that the Microsoft Access query requires two input parameters, i.e current month and previous month.

Based on the input, the Access query will select certain values from a table that fit the criteria and then make certain calculations only for these values.

If I use the import function in Excel I receive an error which states that two inputs were expected but not given.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Thank you!

MS Access sql code is similar to this:

```
Select

table1.value,
table2.value,
table1.value * table2.value as product,

From(

select * 
(from table 1 where date = current month)

inner join

select *
(from table 2 where date = previous month))
```

(current and previous month are popup input variables)

Comment: Are the parameters popup input prompts? I NEVER use these. Reference controls on form for user input. However, since you are probably in Excel and pulling data, this likely will not help. Will have to redesign to not use dynamic parameters on the Access side. How are you importing the data? VBA behind Excel? Edit question to show code.

Comment: Yes the parameters are popup input parameters. What do you mean by reference controls? What is an alternative to popup input parameters?
Currently I cannot import the data because it will not allow me with any method I have tried. If possible I would write a macro that includes the ms access sql code which references a certain cell (s) that has the dates.

Comment: Controls on Access form but since you are running code in Excel, Access form will not be helpful. I expect Excel VBA will have to connect to Access and open a recordset with an SQL statement which includes parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access query object cannot have dynamic parameters. Excel will have to provide the criteria. Following is an example of Excel pulling data from Access.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
cn.Open ""Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='C:\Users\June\LabData.accdb'"
strStateNum = InputBox("Enter State Number", "State Number")
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM GeoDataAll WHERE StateNum='" & strStateNum & "';", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Instead of InputBox, can reference cell to provide parameter.

Your query in Excel like:

```
rs.Open "SELECT Q1.*, field1 * field2 AS Product FROM (" & _
           "(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE [date] = " & cell for current month & ") AS T1 " & _
           "INNER JOIN " & _
           "(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE [date] = " & cell for previous month & ") AS T2 " & _
           "ON T1.ID=T2.ID) " & _
        "AS Q1;", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Then use CopyFromRecordset method to write the data to a range on worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So if access cannot have dynamic parameters does that mean I have to have fixed values for "current month" & "previous month" for the vba import to work? I am not sure what you mean by dynamic parameters and excel providing the criteria.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, I was not able to get it to work and I would like to avoid using the SQL string since the ms access sql code is 100+ lines. I have been trying to use the qdf.parameters function to insert the values into the query. Is this possible in my case? I have not been able to get it to work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao

Comment: Did you add PARAMETERS clause to your query object? Perhaps you need to start a new question with details on your attempt.

Comment: I posted a new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062692/how-to-send-parameters-to-microsoft-access-query-so-that-i-can-import-an-access