# How to send parameters to microsoft access query so that I can import an access parameter query to excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, parameters

I need to import a microsoft access query that has popup input parameters into excel. I tried the code below but it does not work. I receive error 93 that tells me that object or object variable is not set.

I would like to be able to reference two cells in excel that contain the values of the current and previous month and then send these values as inputs to the access query, but for now I entered them in VBA to keep it simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

```
Sub Acess_Connection()
     Dim dbs As DAO.Database
     Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
     Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
     Dim i As Long
     Dim wsh As Worksheet

     Set dbs = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("filepath")                         
     Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("parameter_query")

     qdf.Parameters("Date_PreviousMonth") = "31.12.2018"
     qdf.Parameters("Date_CurrentMonth") = "31.01.2019"

     Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset("parameter_query")          
     Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet1")

     For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1   
         wsh.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rst.Fields(i).Name      
     Next

     wsh.Range("A1").Resize(ColumnSize:=rst.Fields.Count).Font.Bold = True
     wsh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

     rst.Close
     Set rst = Nothing
     dbs.Close
     Set dbs = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: "does not work" means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Do you have PARAMETERS clause in the query object? Need to have `Option Explicit` in every module header. There is a spelling error for variable: `Set qfd` should be `Set qdf`.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by a parameters clause, so I am not sure. Thank you for your feedback. By it does not work I mean I receive error "Data type conversion failure" error 3421 and the set rst line is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: PARAMETERS clause (or declaration) in query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-declaration-microsoft-access-sql. See Gustav's answer about the conversion error. I assume you are replacing `filepath` and `parameter_query` with appropriate info.

Comment: No I implicitly declared the parameters, i.e: select * from table1 where date = date_CurrentMonth. (where "date" is a column in "table1"). And yes I corrected the spelling error

Comment: I have a workbook that used DAO recordset to pull data from Access but can no longer get that to work. Hope you have better luck.

Comment: Had to select `Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library` in VBA editor references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested setting query parameters via VBA with a very simple query and it works with following adjustments.

1. query object must have PARAMETERS clause and parameters under appropriate field(s)
2. use `#` delimiters for date criteria `#12/31/2018#`
3. `Set rst = qdf` line does not use query name as argument, the variable `qdf` provides the name so correct to
   `Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()` which will use the default recordset type.
4. for early binding, select `Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library` in VBA editor, at least for more recent versions of Excel

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I got it to work by making it a parameter query and changing the data type in excel from short text to date. I kept the input at "31.12.2018" and it still worked.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to pass valid date values to the parameters:

```
qdf.Parameters("Date_PreviousMonth").Value = #12/31/2018#
qdf.Parameters("Date_CurrentMonth").Value = #01/31/2019#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding square brackets around your parameters name so:

```
qdf.Parameters("[" & "Date_PreviousMonth" & "]") = "31.12.2018"
```

Comment: Brackets are only needed if names have spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception), however, they shouldn't hurt. Concatenation is not needed, but again, shouldn't hurt.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: Also, if names are reserved words, use brackets. So advise to avoid these conditions in naming convention.