# MS Access Loop through query Recordsets/Rows and output results as an Excel attachment in an Email

Tags: ms-access

I am just looking for some direction as all of my attempts to create a successful loop have failed.

I have a table named "tblContacts" which has 4 fields - ID (primary key), ACCT NUM, CONTACT NAME, CONTACT EMAIL.

Within the same database I have a query named "qryLPContact" which has multiple fields - ID (primary key), ACCT NUM, CONTACT NAME, etc....

The qryContactLP can have the same ACCT NUM on there multiple times but with different information in other fields. My end goal is to Loop through my query results and perform the following:
1. Find the CONTACT EMAIL in tblContact by using the ID field from qryContactLP
2. Loop through the qryContactLP results and find all matching IDs
---stop or pause the loop
3. Create an output as an excel attachment for the ID
4. Move to the next ID on the qryContactLP and output as excel and attach

I have gotten pretty far in the code but still cannot get the above to work. The email and loop work well except for the fact that I get a separate email for every record and it only includes the ID. I need the entire record.

For example qryContactLP results below:

```
ID ACCT NUM CLIENT NAME EMP ID BRANCH  
1  1243567  RUBY        99655  25  
2  7654321  PAUL        99622  18  
2  7654321  PAUL        99354  18  
2  7654321  PAUL        99712  18  
3  5678439  SAM         857632 32
```

The expected result would be for me to have 3 emails generated. However, I receive 5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am on week 2 and I still can't figure this out.

```
Sub loopTable()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    strSQL = "SELECT *FROM qryContactLP WHERE  [ACCT NUM] IN (SELECT [ACCT NUM] FROM qryContactLP WHERE  ID = ID)"   'define the SQL result that you want to loop
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        While (Not rs.EOF)
              Debug.Print rs.Fields("ID")
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested query criteria makes no sense. Also, missing a space after the * character.

The easiest approach for exporting data is attaching a PDF of the desired dataset and a filtered report is easiest way to do that.

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            DoCmd.OpenReport "reportname", acViewPreview, , "ID = " & rs!ID
            DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "reportname", acFormatPDF, rs![contact email], , , "subject text here", "message text here", True
            DoCmd.Close acReport, "reportname", acSaveNo
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you want email sent without review, set the EditMessage argument to False.

Some simple reports can export to Excel. So instead of acFormatPDF, try acFormatXLS.

Exporting a dynamic filtered query object would need code using QueryDefs to set the parameters with values. Example in [How to send parameters to microsoft access query so that I can import an access parameter query to excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062692/how-to-send-parameters-to-microsoft-access-query-so-that-i-can-import-an-access/55063945#55063945)

Embedding multiple records in email body requires HTML code tags to build a table and also uses Outlook automation. SendObject will not work for this. One example [Access VBA To Send Query Results to Outlook Email in Table Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741735/access-vba-to-send-query-results-to-outlook-email-in-table-format)

Comment: Hi June, thank you for the input. If I can't use Excel that's OK. What I am truly struggling with (even with your code provided) is sending/ creating a report for each ID. So in looking at the table I provided earlier. I need 1 report per ID. This is to say, if the ID is on the query 3 times I need 1 report that list all rows for that ID and 1 email to that specific client. Your code sends a report with all IDs on it. Is there a way to do this in Access?

Comment: The code I posted is Access VBA.The report should open filtered to specific ID. All this works for me. However, since I don't really know your data structure nor report design, hard to advise specifics.

Comment: Hi June, I don't have a form or any filtering. I simply have query results. I created a report based off of the query results and applied your code. When executed, the report includes all rows from the query verse just one ID from the query. The code loops through each row. What I am needing is to have the loop find all accounts with the same ID from the query results and send that information to the specified client.

Comment: Sorry, I did forget to include the `acViewPreview` parameter in the OpenReport arguments in the posted code. Were you getting prints as well as email? That would be reason the emailed report was not filtered. See edited answer.